# How to check CAShapeLayer is visible on screen or not - Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, swift5, cashapelayer

I want to check if `CAShapeLayer` is visible on screen or not. Does anybody now how to do?

Comment: ```isHidden```?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily) tell if any of its content is actually **visible**, but you can see if it is contained by another layer by checking its `superlayer` property, and check if it's hidden by checking its `isHidden` property.

Even if it is not hidden and is a sublayer of a layer that's onscreen, it might be covered by other opaque layers. Figuring out if any of its pixels are visible would be much more complex.